# Game restart PyQT4 Python

Tags: python, pyqt4, restart

I've done simple Hangman game using PyQT4. But i have trouble with creating restart() method.

I tried:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
    MainWindow.resize(1188, 696)
    MainWindow.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: black;"))
    self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
    self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
    self.buttons = []
    self.setUpKeyboard()
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1188, 25))
    self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.pic = QtGui.QLabel(self.mainwindow)
    self.pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(os.getcwd() + "/img/s0.jpg"))
    self.pic.setGeometry(50, 150, 450, 280)
    self.pic.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pic"))

....

def restartGame(self):
    self.wordLabel.setText(" ")
    for i in range(26):
        self.buttons[i].setParent(None)
    self.counterLabel.setParent(None)
    self.keyWordHidden = ""
    self.keyWord = ""
    self.pic.setParent(None)
    self.setupUi(self.centralwidget)
```

In other words im deleting every object created. Somehow i get output:

```
MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
AttributeError: 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'setCentralWidget'
```

I'm running out of ideas what i need to pass as argument when i want call my setUpUi() for the second time...

Got another question. My restart works almost fine. But i got another problem. The pixmap that contains graphic element (hanging device building up elements one by one - 10 jpg files like img1, img2...).
For the first gameplay it works fine. After 9 mistakes the whole UI should be re-build... But then the pixmap doesn't show up... I tried to remove

```
self.pic.setParent(None)
```

and just again switching the "img10.jpg" for "img1.jpg". But this does not help.

Comment: The central widget that you created on the main window obviously isn't usable as a main window, but that's what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The central widget that you created on the main window obviously isn't a main window, it's a widget on a window. So of course trying to use it as `MainWindow` isn't going to work.

If you want to reuse the same main window, you need to hold onto it so you can reuse it. There may be a better place to do this—it's hard to see how you're using this class without any of the relevant code—but one obvious thing to do is to just store it in `setupUI`:

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
    MainWindow.resize(1188, 696)
    self.mainwindow = MainWindow
    # …
```

… and then you can reuse it:

```
def restartGame(self):
    # …
    self.setupUi(self.mainwindow)
```

Comment: I did that. One of Widgets (1 out of 15) doesn't seem to be recreated...